# HowTo: How can I default "function" not "Function" as first option for auto-complete when working in .js files

Tags: javascript, resharper, resharper-8.1

Not sure when this started happening, but now my intellisense auto-completion is suggesting and using "Function (in DHtml.js, ...)" when I need it to be "function" while working in .js files.

How do I configure this option?

Comment: I Have the same problem and it's annoying like hell ...

Comment: I think this is about the 4th time I've seen this question on SO, don't people search for answers first? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in the 8.2 EAP builds - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-400812 (note that ticket says fixed in build 8.1.1000. That build isn't 8.1, and isn't available - it's been replaced by 8.2). Please can you try the EAP build and see if it fixes the problem? If not, please update the YouTrack ticket.

If you don't want to use the EAP build, I think you can work around the issue by clearing the solution's cache (ReSharper -> Options -> General -> Clear cache). As I understand it, the reason you're getting `Function` instead of `function` is due to ReSharper tracking selected items and giving previously selected items preference. Clearing the cache clears the tracked values and should allow you to use `function` again, but you might encounter the issue again at a later date.